# Db2/sql: Select & update oldest entries with join

Tags: sql, datetime, db2, sql-update, subquery

if it's given 2 tables:

- Car (fields: c.id, c.name, c.plate)
- Parking (fields: p.position, p.id, p.date, p.time)

When a car enters a parking zone, there will be stored on table "Parking" the p.id (which is normally empty ' ' with the same entry c.id) and p.date (format: 2020-11-23, normally null 0001-01-01) and p.time (format: 08.00.59, normally null 00.00.00).

Sometimes the program on i series reserves for 1 car more than 1 parking position.

Then I have to find out the oldest entries of this car and empty than the field p.id ' '. It's only allowed that 1 car reserves 1 parking position.

How can I update all thd oldest parking p.id fields to ' '? Only the youngest entry (according to p.date and p.time can exist)?

Example:

```
C.id c.name c.plate
3643 volvo. H-FZ25

P.position p.id  p.date.     P.time
R154       3643  2020-11-22  04.34.44
R154       3643  2020-11-22  05.34.44
R154       3643  2020-11-22  07.34.44
```

Only the last entry may remain, for the older entries of the Parking table the field p.id (' '), p.date and p.time should be cleared. How can I select/display first these duplicate entries and update them?

Sorry for my bad english. Thank you for your quick help GMB.

But now I've that situation, that 2 positions were blocked from same car, but with same date and same time (same second!). How can I remove all positions of this car except the last row/position of the duplicate entries (but only if duplicate have same date and time)?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly:

```
update parking p
set pid = null, pdate = null, ptime = null
where exists (  
    select 1
    from parking p1 
    where 
        p1.pid = p.pid 
        and (p1.date > p.date or (p1.date = p.date and p1.time > p.time))
)
```

Basically this sets the column to `nulls` on rows for which a more recent row exists for the same `pid`. If you want empty strings instead, you can just change the `set` clause accordingly.

Note that storing the date and time in two separate columns makes the logic unnecessarily more complex. If these are strings (as they seem to), we might also phrase the condition as:

```
and p1.date || p1.time > p.date || p.time
```

Comment: now I've that situation, that 2 positions were blocked from same car, but with same date and same time (same second!). How can I remove all positions of this car except 1 position which has the biggest position number (but only if duplicate date and time data)?

Comment: It is best to keep the last entry (last row/position from the duplicate id number), the oldest entries should be updated. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Butterfly: you would need to change the `where` clause of the subquery to: `and (p1.date > p.date or (p1.date = p.date and p1.time > p.time) or (p1.date = p.date and p1.time = p.time and p1.position > p.position))`.

Comment: Thank you GMB. Is it possible to change the where clause, so that only the last row, I mean the last entry for the same id will keeped, and the first row till penultimate row of the same id will updated? Many thanks..